# How to use pandas to read the files from argparse?

Tags: python, pandas, argparse

I am using argparse library to read the file to perform the comparison between two excel files.
This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import argparse

if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-FILE_1', '--file_1', type=str, required=True, action='append')
    parser.add_argument('-FILE_2', '--file_2', type=str, required=True, action='append')
    args = parser.parse_args()

def comparison():
    df1=pd.read_excel(args.file_1)
    df2=pd.read_excel(args.file_2)

    comparison_values = df1.values == df2.values
    rows,cols=np.where(comparison_values==False)

    for item in zip(rows,cols):
        df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]] = '{} --> {}'.format(df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]],df2.iloc[item[0], item[1]])

    df1.to_excel('./Excel_diff.xlsx', 'Sheet2', index=False,header=True)

comparison()
```

When I input the command into the terminal,

```
PS C:\Users\Documents\Excel Comparison Proj> python .\excel_comparison.py -FILE_1 "Testing.xlsx" -FILE_2 "Testing - Copy.xlsx"
```

There is an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
"C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 1187
        print "EXTERNSHEET(b7-):"
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
```

Any suggestion to fix the issue so that the python can read the file from `args.file_1` and `args.file_2`?

Comment: In Python 3 print has to have parentheses, e.g `print('hello'). It looks like xlrd is the Python 2 version. I am not sure how this happened but I would look into creating a virtual environment so you have a clean starting point.

Comment: @MattClarke, so what should I do in order to have a clean starting point?

Comment: By creating a virtual environment it is similar to having a clean install of Python (e.g. no 3rd party libraries installed). Once the virtual environment is activated whatever you install is only installed for that environment, so you will need to pip install pandas in it.  This link gives a good explanation on the process including how to do it on Windows: https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/

Comment: Try it and see if your original problem goes away.